# How to make an option always display no matter what the input value is?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a dynamic `<datalist>` for input.

So I wrote this:

```
<input type="text" id="newLocationName" list="addressSuggestions" onkeyup="suggestAddress()" autocomplete="off">
<datalist id="addressSuggestions"></datalist>
```

And `suggestAddress()` will add some options into datalist based on the result it get from Google Geocoding API.

```
"<option value='" + results[i].formatted_address + "'>"
```

But, the problem is, sometimes the address do not contains the input string, so the option won't display since the value does not match user's input.

For example, when I typed in `gee`, the geocoding API will return the address `Gée, 50300 Saint-Jean-de-la-Haize, France`. `Gée` doesn't match `gee`. So it won't display.

So I wonder if there is a way to make the option always show no matter what user typed in.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I solved this problem by using [jQuery autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search)

Simply search option by empty string when key is up (or whenever you what the options to pop up) using `$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "search", "" );`

Comment: IMO, it is a limitation of the `datalist` element. You should probably do it the "old way" with an autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `datalist` behaviour is defined by the browser and (currently) it seems that there is no way of doing what you desire.

Two options are:

1. Normalize your results (for instance pre-processing "Gée" to "Gee"
   before adding it as an `option`). You'll probably want to keep a
   mapping for the original text somewhere to be used later.
2. Use a more powerful component such as [typehead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) which allows you to define a custom `matcher` and define that Gée == Gee for this purpose.

   ```
   var matcher = function(results) {
     return function findMatches(query, callback) {
       var matches = [];
       var regex = new RegExp(query, 'i');
       results.forEach(function(result) {
         if(regex.test(result.replace('é', 'e'))) { //etc
           matches.push(result);
         }
       });
       callback(matches);
     };
   };

   var results = ...;

   $('.typeahead').typeahead({
     hint: true,
     highlight: true,
     minLength: 1
   },
   {
     name: 'addresses',
     source: matcher(results)
   });
   ```

Comment: In fact, I managed to do that by using jQuery autocomplete. Simply search "" when key is up. $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "search", "" );. Thanks anyway